# ARPSpoof to redirect all traffic from Wi-Fi to ethernet

Tags: router

I have 2 routers. The first Router is connected to the Internet and the second one is an old model I found.

Now I want to open a Wi-Fi Hotspot on the old Router without the Internet and connect my laptop to it through ethernet.

From my laptop I also want to connect with WLAN to the router connected to the Internet and try with an ARPSpoof to force all traffic from the hotspot (that Im wire connected) through my laptops WLAN interface to the router connected to the Internet.

In short: Im connected to 2 LANs, one by Wi-Fi (with Internet) - the other by ethernet (without Internet). I want to spoof the Wi-Fi non Internet LAN that way, that all traffic from that network will come to my ethernet interface und get prerouted through my WLAN interface to the other router.

I realy tried a bunch of times but I cant handle it. Can you tell me how to do that and also is it possible what I want to reach?